# jQuery validate plugin - only success show 'tick' image otherwise on error show 'cross' image

Tags: jquery, validation, jquery-validate

I am trying to use the jQuery validate plugin to validate my form fields on the fly, when an error is found I want to show an red 'cross' image otherwise if it has passed the validation to show a green 'tick' image.

I have got half way there - the green tick shows when an entry has passed the validation, however I cannot get the red cross image to show. I know i'll need to use the errorPlacement function in some way to get this working.

At the moment the it shows the green tick fine - i just am trying to get the same effect but with a red cross on an error.

Here is the code so far.. I've added this to jsfiddle if its easier to view there
http://jsfiddle.net/BLDXC/3/

```
    $('#checkout-form').validate({
    rules: {
        first_name: {
            minlength: 2,
            required: true
        },
        last_name: {
            minlength: 2,
            required: true
        },
        terms: {
          required: true,
        }
    },
    highlight: function (element) {
        $(element).addClass('#nonvalid')
          .closest('.form-group').removeClass('valid');
    },
    success: function (element) {
        element.addClass('valid')
          .closest('.form-group').removeClass('error');
    }
});


<style type="text/css">
label.valid {
  position: relative;
  top: -25px;
  right: 10px;
  float: right;
  width: 16px;
  height: 16px;
  background: url('/assets/images/icons/tick.png') center center no-repeat;
  display: inline-block;
  text-indent: -9999px;
}

label.nonvalid {
  position: relative;
  top: -25px;
  right: 10px;
  float: right;
  width: 16px;
  height: 16px;
  background: url('/assets/images/icons/cross.png') center center no-repeat;
  display: inline-block;
  text-indent: -9999px;
}

</style>
```

Comment: your css class nonvalid != error ///////////// .addClass('#error') ? did you mean .addClass('error') ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to use the `unhighlight` callback function along with `highlight` as they are complimentary functions.  When there's an error message, `highlight` will fire.  When the error message should be cleared away, `unhighlight` fires.

Something like this can be used to properly toggle images that are part of your CSS...

Proof of concept: http://jsfiddle.net/BwqWh/

```
highlight: function (element) {
    $(element).addClass('error').removeClass('valid')
         .closest('.form-group').addClass('error').removeClass('valid');
},
unhighlight: function (element) {
    $(element).addClass('valid').removeClass('error')
        .closest('.form-group').addClass('valid').removeClass('error');
}
```